# Use CEILING Without the Effect of Rounding Error

Tags: fortran, fortran90, intrinsics

I'm trying to use the intrinsic function ‘CEILING’, but the rounding error makes it difficult to get what I want sometimes. The sample code is just very simple:

```
PROGRAM MAIN

  IMPLICIT NONE

  INTEGER, PARAMETER        ::      ppm_kind_double = KIND(1.0D0)
  REAL(ppm_kind_double)     ::      before,after,dx

  before = -0.112
  dx = 0.008
  after = CEILING(before/dx)

  WRITE(*,*) before, dx, before/dx, after

  END
```

And I got results:[image]

The value I give to 'before' and 'dx' in the code is just for demonstration. For those before/dx = -13.5 for example, I want to use CEILING to get -13. But for the picture I show, I actually want to get -14. I have considered using some arguments like

```
 IF(ABS(NINT(before/dx) - before/dx) < 0.001)
```

But that's simply not beautiful. Is there any better way to do this?

Update:

I was surprised to find that the problem won't occur if I set the variables to constants in ppm_kind_double. So I guess this 'rounding error' will only happen when the number of digits for rounding accuracy of the machine I use is more than what's defined in ppm_kind_double. I actually run my program(not this demo code) on a cluster, which I don't know about the machine precision. So maybe it's quad precision on that machine that leads to the problem?

After I set constants to double precision:

```
before = -0.112_ppm_kind_double
dx = 0.008_ppm_kind_double
```

[image]

Comment: You threw me a bit off with wanting -14. It took my a while to realise that -0.112 / 0.008 is exactly -14, but because of rounding errors, the result is slightly more, and the `CEILING` then amplifies this minuscule error.

Comment: @chw21, actually I saw your earlier comment and was waiting for you to find that. :)

Comment: Given precision is part of the issue here, it is worth noting that your literal constants are only single precision - e.g. `-0.112` should probably be written `-0.112_ppm_kind_double`.  This change won't solve the underlying issue though.

Comment: In addition to making the constants of consistent data type, it's difficult to guess why you didn't use ANINT rather than CEILING.

Comment: @lanH Thanks for the remainder.

Comment: @tim18 Because I also want to get for example -13 from -13.6

Comment: You don't have to do any `--- UPDATE 10/11/2016------`, this site has an automatic version control. Just see the link "edited ..." below your post.

Comment: BTW your interpretation is wrong. What actually happened is that originally you were setting your variables to inaccurate single precision and with the kind suffix you are using the correct precision. I highly suggest you to read about numerical accuracy of expressions in Fortran. Default numbers are single precision. And your *"rounding accuracy of the machine"* does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tricky, because you never know where the rounding error comes from. If `dx` was just a tiny bit larger than `0.008` then the division `before/dx` might still be rounded to the same value, but now `-13` would be the correct answer.

That said, the most common method around that that I have seen is to just *nudge* the previous value ever so little into the opposite direction. Something like this:

```
program sign_test
    use iso_fortran_env
    implicit none
    real(kind=real64) :: a, b
    integer(kind=int32) :: c
    a = -0.112
    b = 0.008
    c = my_ceiling(a/b)
    print*, a, b, c
contains
    function my_ceiling(v)
        implicit none
        real(kind=real64), intent(in) :: v
        integer(kind=int32) :: my_ceiling
        my_ceiling = ceiling(v - 1d-6, kind=int32)
    end function my_ceiling
end program sign_test
```

This won't have any impact on the vast majority of values, but there are now a few values that will get rounded up by more than intended.

Comment: Thanks chw21, give the initial guess a reasonable shift is also a good way.

Answer (score 0):

note if your reals are notionally "exact" to a specified precision you might do something like this:

```
 after=nint(1000*before)/nint(1000*dx)
```

this works for your example.. you haven't said what you'd expect for both values positive and so on so you might need to work it a bit.